# Scala/Spark's flatmap with repeated function calls

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flatmap

Say I have following code.

```
def f(x): (Array[Double], Array[Int])={
    val   data: Array[Double]   //1D array
    val   index: Array[Int]    //Data element's index

    //Read data from a file into "data"
    //Generate index (based on value "x") into "index"

    (dset_datas, index)
}

sc.range(0, 10, 1, 10).flatMap.(x => (f(x)._1 zip f(x)._2))
```

Questions:

1) Will the function f(x) be called twice for each x within flatmap? Since I called f(x)._1 first and then f(x)._2.

2) Will flapmap be executed (especfially the data reading part) in parallel? Say I had 3 nodes and each node has 32 cores. I set --num-executors=2 and --executor-cores=32. Another node is used as driver node.

To answer the above questions, I searched docs for Spark/Scala a lot but didn't get any answers from there. I tried to run the code on my own system. It looks like that

1) f(x) is called twice because I found the data partitions are processed twices. But, I am not sure.

2) I noticed two executor folder are created under the spark log file system also some stdout from each executor. But, I am not sure too.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1) Every worker will execute `f(x)` twice, since it's being invoked two times in your function literal - each time extracting different element of the resulting tuple.

2) The last parameter of your `range` method is `10`, which means that your range RDD will have 10 partitions. This means that the upper bound of parallel executions of that `flatMap` is 10 (if you'd have 10 executors, `flatMap` could be executed parallelly on every of those executors). Since you have two executors, `flatMap` would still be executed in parallel, but only on those two executors.